# Send SMS / MMS Text Message over Wifi instead of Data plan using SMSManager

Tags: android, sms, mms, smsmanager

Is it possible to send SMS / MMS over wifi if the phone's carrier service is not working?

I have an app setup and it is sending and receiving text messages over the phone's data plan, but I want to send text messages over wifi instead. Right now it just fails over wifi.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: no. that's not how SMS works. unless you use a third party, such as twilio to send the messages for you, or unless you are sending messages that are not SMSs, such as whatsapp messages.

Comment: SMS messages are special messages that go over the dead space in the cellular communications protocol.  That format just doesn't exist in wifi.  Now there are services that send SMS to phone numbers over a computer network, using one of them might work.

Comment: ahh gotcha this makes sense. I would have to roll my own backend to do "SMS" over wifi

Comment: If one of you guys can write a clear defined answer explaining the protocols ill accept it

Answer (score 0):

To do that you would need to setup an sms/mms gateway from scratch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway and I really doubt that's what you want to do.

It involves contracts with carriers and much more then just technical issues.  As mentioned in a comment twillio is a pretty great way to get at it. There's a bunch of other options if you lookup sms web apis

https://www.twilio.com/ gives you a simple api to send sms/mms and more.

For the Android specific lib checkout https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android